# How to prevent substitution of $1 value, while passing the argument value as 'abc$1xyz' in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

foo()
{
   echo $1;        
}
foo $1
```

running the script as: **./test.sh abc$1xyz**

Output is:

```
abcxyz
```

But expecting output is:

```
abc$1xyz
```

So, here $1 value is replacing with empty, but I want to prevent that. I know we can do with using single quotes like **foo 'abc$1xyz'** but actually I can't do that, because that value will passing from third person, I can't tell them to add single quotes or any escaping characters. So, please let me know is there any other work around will be available for this.

**Edit:** Based on the requested comments, and please tell me still you need any clarity the one who had down voted this.

Comment: Do you want `foo` to echo without any variable substitution? e.g. do you want the actual output to be `abc$1xyz` as `echo`'ed by `foo`? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Re: "I know we can do with using single quotes like **foo 'abc$1xyz'** butactually I can't do that, because that value will come from outside": I don't understand. Where is "outside", and what value is coming from there, and why does that mean you can't use single-quotes?

Comment: Please read my answer, I can not think of any other way to interpret your request. Please expand the description.

Comment: @sorontar Thanks for your help, please check once my edited question. I had understood your answer, but I can't force them to do that who ever executing my script.

Comment: @ruakh check once my edited question, actually 'outside; means the one who are executing my script file. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @F.Hauri let's assume my password is 'abc$1xyz' then in this case what you can do?

Comment: You have added an additional twist to the question. Is `$1` in the call `./test abc$1xyz` meant to be a variable value? If it is part of an string, just use a back slash to quote it.

Comment: Due to new to the shell script, I don't know how shell script behave regarding this situation, after reading @Bryan reply I got it. But still I didn't understood on what basis my question deserved downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't do what you want. If someone is using your tool from the command line, they simply must use your command according to the rules of the shell.

The behavior you are seeing is because the shell will translate the argument *before your program ever sees it*. There is absolutely no way for your command to affect what happens before it is called.

It is because of this -- because the shell processes arguments *before* running your script -- that quotes were created in the first place. Quoting (both single quotes, double quotes, and backslash quotes) exists to give users control over how arguments are treated *before* calling some function.

So, if you want a string like `abc$1xyz` to be sent to your program without variable expansion you have two choices:

- require the user to use some other shell that doesn't translate arguments before calling your program, or
- require the user to use the facilities of the shell to properly quote their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() { echo "$1"; }

foo "$1"
```

On execution, will do this:

```
$ set -- "Hello World"
$ test.sh "abc${1}xyz"
abcHello Worldxyz
```

---

If what you want is that the output string has a `$`, then run this:

```
$ set -- "Hello World"
$ test.sh "abc\$1xyz"
abc$1xyz
```

I can not think of any other way to interpret your request.

Answer (score 1):

Your script would look like this

```
#!/bin/bash

foo()
{
   echo $1;
}
foo $1
```

Execute like this: `./test.sh 'abc$1xyz'`

---

**EDIT:**

Why not use something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter input"

read input

foo()
{
   echo $1;
}
foo $input
```

Execute: `./test.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, because I have the impression that you still have not got the point:

I have the impression - and this is what makes your post confusing - that you are searching a way to change your **script** to achieve the desired behaviour. That's technically not possible, because you are referring to the $1 in `abc$1xyz`, and not the two `$1` I can see in your script.

In the way your script gets called, the *$1* in `abc$1xyz` is never seen by your script; it is substituted **before** your script gets called, on the calling side. To change this behaviour, you would need to program a time machine which travels in the past and undoes this change.

If the caller of your script wants the *$1* be passed literally, s/he has to care about it - see for instance the response by @yogur.